# Compile gradle library project with another library project as an external dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two independent libraries projects in android and both have some shared classes data.
I want to create a new library 'Dependency' that will contain all the shared classes data.

My android libs stracture looks like this :

```
LibA
  |--build.gradle
  |--settings.gradle
LibB
  |--build.gradle
  |--settings.gradle
Dependency
  |--build.gradle
```

note that my libraries are on different folders.

I've looked at this example [link](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/) but it doesn't seem to work with libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Create the library "Dependency" and put all the shared classes in it.

Import the "LibB" library in the "LibA" module by using the below code in the  `build.gradle` file of the "LibA" module.

```
api project(":LibB")
```

Now, import the "LibA" library in the "Dependency" module by using the below code in the `build.gradle` file of the "Dependency" module.

```
api project(":LibA")
```

The result is that "Dependency" extends "LibA" which further extends "LibB" library and hence "Dependency" can use the classes of both the "LibA" and "LibB" library.

Comment: I dont want "LibA" to extends  "LibB" . i want 'Dependeny' to extend both 'libA' and 'libB'

Comment: @Jonny Updated the answer.